# How to test whether one cohort is a mixture of two other cohorts for a set of binary variables?

Tags: bayesian, binary-data, multinomial-distribution, mixture-distribution

I'll illustrate my question with an example. Suppose I have 25 observations for 3 binary variables. The observations belong to 3 pre-labelled cohorts 1, 2, and 3. Let's say:

```
n1 <- 10
n2 <- 8
n3 <- 7
```

are the n's for each cohort. Each cohort has a set of parameters determining the probability of each variable being 1 or 0. So for cohort 1:

```
p1 <- c(.97, .05, 0.03)
```

Note that the values don't need to sum to 1; x1 and x2 can both equal 1 for the same observation; I'm just using a simple example where they tend not to. The data for the three cohorts might thus looks like:

```
m1 <- sapply(1:3,function(i){sample(c(1,0), n1, prob = c(mu1[i], 1-mu1[i]), replace = TRUE)})
m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    1
 [2,]    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    0
 [5,]    1    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    0
 [7,]    1    0    1
 [8,]    1    0    0
 [9,]    1    0    0
[10,]    1    0    0

p2 <- c(.01, .95, 0.05)
m2 <- sapply(1:3,function(i){sample(c(1,0), n2, prob = c(mu2[i], 1-mu2[i]), replace = TRUE)})
m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0
[6,]    0    1    0
[7,]    0    1    0
[8,]    0    1    0

p3 <- c(0.03, 0.02, 0.96)
m3 <- sapply(1:3,function(i){sample(c(1,0), n3, prob = c(mu3[i], 1-mu3[i]), replace = TRUE)})
m3
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    1
[6,]    1    0    1
[7,]    0    0    1
```

My question is, in essence, how might I design a test to ascertain whether m3 is in fact a mixture of members of m1 and m2? Or, put more mathematically, how to determine if p3 is a linear combination of p1 and p2, given the observed data (obviously in this case it isn't, but this is of course a toy example)?

My first thought was to just use a Bayesian model and determine the probability of observing the data given a bunch of sets of vectors chosen for p1, p2, and p3 (either random or using a grid), then take all vectors for which p3 = a*p1 + (1 - a)*p2, across all values for a between 0 and 1, and divide by the sum across all sets of vectors to get an estimate of the likelihood of observing the data given p3 being a linear combination of p1 and p2. The problem is that parameter sets for which p3 is indeed exactly a linear combination are unlikely to occur via either sampling method.

I also thought (but am not certain) that this question may be simplified by taking the column sums of each cohort, then treating each as an observation derived from a multinomial distribution.

```
s1 <- colSums(m1)
s1
[1] 10  0  2

s2 <- colSums(m2)
s2
[1] 0 7 0

s3 <- colSums(m3)
s3
[1] 0 1 5
```

But wasn't sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the case that your interpolated distributions are fixed: If you have a continuous prior over your model space the probability mass of an exact combination will always be 0 for a standard probability measure. So instead of testing for an exact linear combination I would test for the probability of an almost linear combination, so all distributions that are within a small distance of a linear combination would be considered linear. If you then also have a prior over your model space, you can numerically integrate the posterior over your volume of "linear" combinations to test whether your hypothesis is true.

If the interpolated distributions are uncertain, you additionally need to evaluate the probability density of points lying on any possible line of possible interpolated distributions. So basically, you first choose one end point from a start point distribution and then another point from the end point distribution along that line. Here it would be challenging to figure out the normalizing constant of the posterior pdf.